# DataGridView Using Microsoft Surface SDK

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, pixelsense

I am using VisualStudio 2010 with Microsoft's Surface SDK 2. I have a C# WPF project where I am trying to implement a touch-responsive DataGrid wrapped into a SurfaceScrollViewer. The scrolling by touch works when the grid is empty, but once the grid gets populated, the highlight events of the DataGrid take over. Has anyone encountered and know of a solution?

Here is my sample XAML:

```
    <Grid>
    <my:SurfaceScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="surfaceScrollViewer" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" >
        <DataGrid Name="dataGrid" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataView}" RowHeight="35" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" HeadersVisibility="None" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" CanUserResizeRows="False" AreRowDetailsFrozen="True" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" Focusable="True" />
    </my:SurfaceScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```